# Android Notifications not displaying when the app force stopped from settings

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Please find below the description for one of the issue posted in my project.

"A user has just reported to my client that she does not receive the Android notifications when the app is hard closed(Force Stop).I have just tested this and can confirm that the notification was not received when the app was hard closed (but it was received if the app was in the background).Can you confirm the expected behaviour? I have discussed this with one of our Android developers and he says that notifications should always be received whether the app has been hard or soft closed."

Please let me know is this expected behavior in android ?,

if yes please provide me some details regarding this.

or

if it is possible to resolve this issue please provide me some samples.

Comment: Could you clarify which notifications were expected, perhaps post the code you expected to result in this and the manifest file? This would all help people give a specific answer to a specific questions ... thanks!

Comment: it is in the documentation the app wont receive broadcasts or be able to notify till it is again restarted (turns as if installed first other than for data)

Answer (score 2):

[read this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html). After force stopped your app wont get any notification. It is completely dead until user will start it manually (via launcher/intent/etc.).

Comment: Ok fine, if i start the app again after force stopped will it shows the previous notifications.

Comment: by notifications you mean android push notifications via GCM?

Comment: Not push notifications, just like reminder notifications or event notifications added in calendar.

Comment: force stop it is almost like uninstall. So all you AlarmManager's alarms will be lost. All events you added to android calendar will be kept. But I still do not undestand what exactly is notification in your case ) Or you have some custom notifications in your app? If so, they wont work.

Comment: Yes, I have some custom notifications.